# Verify if data already in db, with more inputs same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have (part of) a form HTML produced by a PHP loop:

```
<input type="text" class="store">
<input type="text" class="store">
<input type="text" class="store">
<input type="text" class="store">
```

The input goes in a db tables:

```
store
-------
cityID
cityname
store
```

I have a JavaScript that alerts me if the store entered is already in other cities:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.store').on('change', function() {
    var storeValue = $('.store').val();
    $.post('stores.php', {'word': storeValue}, function(data) {
      var verifStore = '';
      var json = $.parseJSON(data);
      $.each(json, function(k, v) {
        verifStore += '[' + v.cityID + '] ' + v.cityName + '\n';
      });
      alert('Already in the following cities: ' + '\n' + verifStore);
    });
  });
});
```

Problem is that JavaScript is fired by the `.class` and I have more `.class` inputs in my form, so (of course) it doesn't work properly. How should I modify my JavaScript code? Maybe there is in JavaScript a way to consider each `.class` field separately... Something like `.each` or `.foreach` ...?

Comment: That is not a form. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar (part of) a form ;) Thanks!

Comment: Man, I was kidding. The main problem here is that there's no `name` attribute defined.

Comment: It was a good point :) !! Do you know how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, you have been asked to put 4 different values for the city and they are not supposed to be present in the DB. I would create a class named `error`:

```css
.error {border: 1px solid #f00; background: #f99;}
```

And now, I would go through each of the `input` using `$.each`:

```
$(".store").each(function () {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.removeClass("error");
  $.post('stores.php', {'word': $this.val()}, function (data) {
    if ( /* Your condition if the word is present. */ )
      alert("Already there!");
  });
});
```

Note that this code will send as many as requests to the server as many inputs are there. So handle with care.

Comment: Thanks! Only think is that values could be repeated in DB, I only would like to be alerted...

Comment: @codeispoetry Just add your alert next to the `addClass`!

Comment: @codeispoetry There's an error in the code. Check? Where is `k;` in my original code? **Error:** `$this = $(this)k;` And the `data` part is also wrong. Man!!!

Comment: Thanks Praven, I changed the date because my json file is never ==yes and  I don't need to add a class, but just display an alert. Could you edit your answer in this way, it would probably be easier... Thanks!!

Comment: Still no luck... I will try later. Hopefully I will find what I'm doing wrong... I will let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: Sure... You may vote up my answer for my efforts? `:)`

Comment: Thanks, after reading your suggestion I was able to modify the code and make it work. I added an answer with full code. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, Praveen, I have this other question that nobody seems to answer. If you have a chance, could you please get a look at it? Thanks for your help! !http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118256/jquery-sortable-with-multiple-lists-and-and-button-to-save-change-conncet-to-my

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your function if you do just one request.

```
var values = $(".store").map(function(){
return this.value;
}); // values is an array

$this.removeClass("error");
// stores.php should be ready to receive an array of values
$.post('stores.php', {'word': JSON.stringify(values)}, function (data) {
     var verifStore  = '';
     var json = $.parseJSON(data);
     $.each(json, function(k, v){
         verifStore  += '[' + v.cityID  + '] ' + v.cityName  + '\n';
     });
     if(varifStore)
          alert('Already in the following cities: ' + '\n' + verifStore);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION (at least for me...)**

After reading all answers and suggestions, I was able to make it work with this code. Hope it will be helpful for others :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('.store').each (function(){//do it for every class .store
    var $this = $(this); //get this object

    $this.on('change', function(){ //when this change...
          var searchValue = this.value; //assign the input to a variable
                if (searchValue != ''){ //if the variable is not emprty
                      $.post('stores.php',{'term' : searchValue}, function(data) { //check and return data in alert

                            if (data.length < 10){ // if number not in db, green
                                $this.css({'border' : 'solid 4px #17BC17'}); 
                            }

                            var resultAlert = '';
                            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                            $.each(jsonData, function(k, v){
                                resultAlert += '[' + v.cityID + '] ' + v.cityname + ' ' + v.value + '\n';
                            }); //each

                            alert('ALERT!' + '\n' + 'store in other cities' + '\n' + searchValue + ': ' + '\n'  + resultAlert );
                            $this.css({'border' : 'solid 4px #FFCC11'}); // if in db, yellow
                      });// post
                }//close if

                if (searchValue == ''){ //if the variable is empty, this turn green, if you delete a yellow number
                    $this.css({'border' : ''}); 
                }


    }); //close on change  
});//close .each
```

});